# Is there a Windows Cortana voice equivalent in Linux?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, software-sources, voice-recognition

I really like Windows Cortana voice or at least the idea of Cortana voice. I'm running ubuntu 16.04. Is there a voice assistant for ubuntu?

Comment: Perhaps Jasper?

Comment: Use Google's voice-based assistant in Chrome or Chromium perhaps?